# If condition on windows load not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is not working and cant understand why. What am I doing wrong?

```
     $(function() {
             var advanced = localStorage['advanced-search'];
             alert(advanced);//this shows true
             if((advanced == "true")|(advanced==true)){
                       //Code never reaches here
                      alert('click');
                    $('#advanced-search').trigger('click');
                    localStorage['advanced-search'] = false;
             }
});
```

Comment: try (advanced == "true")||(advanced==true)

Comment: what does the console say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the OR operator. It should be like -

```
if((advanced == "true")||(advanced==true)){
```

Answer (score 3):

This expression is not working:

```
if((advanced == "true")|(advanced==true)){
```

It’s enough to do:

```
if(advanced) {
```

because `"true"` as a  string is also "truthy".

Comment: @AkashDeshpande if `alert(avanced)` yields "true" and `if(advanced)` is false in your code, then you probably have a syntax error somewhere. You need to show us a fiddle or something that recreates your problem.

Comment: Sorry its working now. There was problem with the local storage get item method.

Comment: @David: if it is string "false" then also it will be "truthy"!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an extra |:

```
$(function() {
             var advanced = localStorage.getItem['advanced-search'];
             alert(advanced);//this shows true
             if((advanced == "true") || (advanced==true)){
                       //Code never reaches here
                      alert('click');
                    $('#advanced-search').trigger('click');
                    localStorage['advanced-search'] = false;
             }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OR operator needs to be two `|`..Like this:

```
if((advanced == "true") || (advanced==true)){
```

If the variable `advanced` is a BOOLEAN, then you can simply use this:

```
if(advanced) {
   // code here..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is mistake in your javascript code.so you can not use "|" instead of "||"
so try by the following code gets solved your error.

```
      $(function() {
         var advanced = localStorage.getItem['advanced-search'];
         alert(advanced);//this shows true
         if((advanced == "true")||(advanced==true)){
                   //Code never reaches here
                  alert('click');
                $('#advanced-search').trigger('click');
                localStorage['advanced-search'] = false;
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say that a proper OR operator is still not working, then I suspect it must be a problem with the case.

Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/VTfQU/**

Use this code to simplify your `if` condition:

```
var advanced = localStorage.getItem['advanced-search'];
advanced = advanced.toString().toLowerCase();
if (advanced == "true") {
    $('#advanced-search').trigger('click');
    localStorage['advanced-search'] = "false";
}
```

The idea is to convert your data into lowercase and then just check the condition on that value. I have added `toString()` just to be safe, anyway getting a value out of local storage will always be a string.